# Typescript :Sort Object by value

Tags: typescript

Input

```
let input = {"ab":"a","cd":"n","kl":"o"}
```

Output

```
let output = {"ab":"a","kl":"o","cd":"n"}
```

Sort the object according to the value..

Comment: Objects are not sortable, as there is no way to guarantee order of keys. [Does ES6 introduce a well-defined order of enumeration for object properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076219/does-es6-introduce-a-well-defined-order-of-enumeration-for-object-properties). Use an array to represent key order you wish.

Answer (score 0):

You need create another object (array) and sort it. Please take a look here.

https://medium.com/@pagalvin/sort-arrays-using-typescript-592fa6e77f1

What you need to do is to define an object similar to JSON, for eg

```
myObject{
key: string;
value: string
}
```

MyPublicKey from the tutorial will be your VALUE in the example object

Hope it helps!

Comment: `{
KEY,
VALUE
}` --- what does this mean?

Comment: @zerkms I updated the response. also, in your original post as an example: 'ab' will be a key and 'a' should be the value